# Rails collection_select not getting an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to understand a little more about how the collection_select from Rails form control works.

Items Controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :category))
    render plain: @item.inspect
    # @item.save
    # redirect_to my_page_path
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category %>
     <%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name,
            { prompt: "Make your selection from the list below"}, { multiple: false, size: 1, class: "custom-select shadow rounded" }) %>
  </div>
```

When I render the code I get category_id = nil

```
#<Item id: nil, name: "Yo", description: "Brand new", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, category_id: nil>
```

Thank you.... any help with some explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more information around the error? Is the category id being populated in the select dropdown? Where did you get the Item with category id as null from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues in the code. You already noticed that the `category_id` is `nil` on the object.

Looking at the form the `collection_select` helper sets a `category_ids`, but your model's attribute is named `category_ids`. Just remove the plural `s`

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name,
        # ... %>
```

The other issue is the configuration of the `StrongParameters` in the controller. Strong params methods are working on the params hash and do not know that a `category` association exists and that this association works with a `category_id`. Therefore your need to be precise and add `category_id` to the list:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :category_id))
  render plain: @item.inspect
  # @item.save
  # redirect_to my_page_path
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
f.collection_select(:category_ids
```

first parameter should be `:category_id` because this is foreign key attribute